# An inequality related to Riesz–Thorin theorem, determinants and $L_p$ norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis, inequalities

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ , $p \in [1, +\infty)$, prove that

$$\left( \sum_{1\leq i < j <k \leq n} \left|  \det\left(\begin{matrix} a_i & b_i & c_i \\
a_j & b_j & c_j \\
a_k & b_k & c_k 
\end{matrix}\right)\right|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq c_p \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \left( \sum_{1\leq j <k \leq n} \left|  \det\left(\begin{matrix}  b_j & c_j \\
 b_k & c_k 
\end{matrix}\right)\right|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} $$

where $c_p = \max(1, 3^{1-\frac{2}{p}})$.

A 2-dimensional analogue of this problem was discussed here:
[An inequality related to Lagrange's identity and $L_p$ norm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298898/an-inequality-related-to-lagranges-identity-and-l-p-norm)

Remark:

1. When $p=1$, the proof is straightforward since 
   $$\left|  \det\left(\begin{matrix} a_i & b_i & c_i \\
   a_j & b_j & c_j \\
   a_k & b_k & c_k 
   \end{matrix}\right)\right| \leq |a_i| \left|  \det\left(\begin{matrix}  b_j & c_j \\
    b_k & c_k 
   \end{matrix}\right)\right| +  |a_j| \left|  \det\left(\begin{matrix}  b_i & c_i \\
    b_k & c_k 
   \end{matrix}\right)\right|  +|a_k| \left|  \det\left(\begin{matrix}  b_i & c_i\\
    b_j & c_j 
   \end{matrix}\right)\right| $$, by Laplace expansion and triangle inequality. Summing up all these inequalities is enough. $p = \infty$ case can be proved in a similar way.

Using Holder's inequality directly on the Laplace expansion gives a weaker bound: $3^{1 - \frac{1}{p}}$

2. When $p=2$,  LHS is the volume of Parallelepiped spanned by three vectors $a,b,c$, while RHS is the norm of $a$ times the area of parallelogram spanned by $b,c$, so the inequality is clearly true. (This fact can be proved by using Cauchy-Binet)
3. As users @fedja and @mahdi suggested in [An inequality related to Lagrange's identity and $L_p$ norm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298898/an-inequality-related-to-lagranges-identity-and-l-p-norm) , this problem is closely related to Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem. However, I find it difficult to apply the theorem directly on my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: If we could prove that 
$$
\sum_{1\leq i,j,k\leq n} |a_i c_{jk}-a_jc_{ik}+a_kc_{ij}|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \right) \left( \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}c_{ij}^2 \right)
$$ 
for all $a \in \mathbb R^n$, and  all $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrix $C=[c_{ij}]$, then Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem  implies your mentioned inequality.

Comment: Yes I have already proved that too. I am a bit busy these days, and will update a proof later. Thank you Mahdi!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem proves a generalized  result. That is,

> **Observation**. for all $a \in \mathbb C^n$, and all $n\times n$ skew-Hermitian matrix $C$, we have
>   $$
> \sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n} |a_i c_{jk}-a_jc_{ik}+a_kc_{ij}|^p \leq c^p_p\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^p \right) \left( \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}c_{ij}^p \right)
> $$ 
>   where $c_p := \max (1,3^{1-2/p})$ and $1\leq p \leq \infty$.

When $p=1,\infty$, above observation is obvious. Also, above observation holds true when $p=2$ (as OP said). Now, by considering a multilinear function $\Lambda$ defined as $[\Lambda(a,C)]_{i,j,k} = a_i c_{jk}-a_jc_{ik}+a_kc_{ij}$
 and interpolating between $1$ and $2$ and then between $2$ and $\infty$, above observation was proved for $1\leq p \leq \infty$ (similar to [the answer of a previous question of OP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298898/an-inequality-related-to-lagranges-identity-and-l-p-norm)).

If we set $c_{ij} := \det \begin{pmatrix}b_i&c_i\\b_j&c_j\end{pmatrix}$ in the above observation, the mentioned inequality of OP follows.